# Ada Thread Switching Using GtkAda

Tags: multithreading, gtk, ada

A task I created doesn't appear to be relinquishing control so that the main thread will run. I'm not sure why. Since this is my first attempt to use multithreading in Ada (under GNAT with GtkAda), I am sure I am missing some basic principle here.

My main looks like this:

```
procedure Main is
begin
   Test_Gui.Gui_Task.Gui_Initialize;
   Test_Gui.Simple_Switch_Test;
   Msg("Done");
end;
```

In the package Test_Gui, the spec and body code look like this:

```
task type Gui_Type is
  entry Gui_Initialize;
  entry Gui_Reset_SwitCh_To_1;
  entry Gui_Display_Message(Message : String);
  entry Gui_Write_Debug;
end Gui_Type;

Gui_Task : Gui_Type;
```

and

```
task body Gui_Type is
begin
   loop
      select
         accept Gui_Initialize  do
            Initialize;
         end Gui_Initialize;
      or
          accept Gui_Reset_Switch_To_1  do
            Reset_Switch_To_1;
         end Gui_Reset_Switch_To_1;
      or
         accept Gui_Display_Message (Message : in String) do
            Display_Message(Message);
         end Gui_Display_Message;
      or
         accept Gui_Write_Debug  do
            Debug_Label.Set_Label(Debug_Label_Text);               
         end Gui_Write_Debug;
      else
         Gdk.Threads.Enter;
         Dead := Gtk.Main.Main_Iteration;
         Gdk.Threads.Leave;
        delay 0.01;
     end select;
  end loop;
end Gui_Type;
```

The second method, Simple_Switch_Test, called from main is this, which invokes a call to the GUI task from within Redisplay_Item_And_Get_Switches.

```
procedure Simple_Switch_Test is

  Text  : String(1..80) := (others => ' ');
  Msg   : String(1..16);

begin
  loop
     Count := Count + 1;
     Copy_String(Integer'Image(Count), Text);
     for I in 1..16 loop
        Msg(I) := Text(I);
     end loop;

     Redisplay_Item_And_Get_Switches(Msg);

     Copy_String("some stuff.."), Debug_Label_Text );

     Gui_Task.Gui_Write_Debug;

     delay 0.01;

  end loop;

end;
```

Initialization works and the GUI functions, even with its callbacks working. However, after the first call to Redisplay_Item_And_Get_Switches from Simple_Switch_Test puts the code into the GUI task loop, it never leaves the else clause, except to handle the callbacks.

Consequently, it never gets to the call to Gui_Task.Gui_Write_Debug and continue that code in the main task.

I have verified this in the debugger.

I thought the delays in each loop would suspend the associated task, but I obviously don't understand it correctly. Is this code fixable without too many changes? (I'm hoping I got the basic skeleton of tasking implemented right.) What is missing or wrong with it?

Comment: I haven't experimented with this design (in Go, not Ada, but same principles/technologies) enough to know why your code doesn't work, or why the delay doesn't work. I will say what you're going to have to do is split this into two tasks. One simply calls `gtk_main()` and handles all the GUI stuff there. The other has all your `Gui_Do_Thing` stuff, using the `g_idle_add()` or `gdk_threads_add_idle()` functions (one of the two) to tell that `gtk_main()` task to do the thing. I don't know what the Ada equivalents would be or how to write them, sorry. Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

The problem I see with this is that Gtkada is layered on top of a non-Ada product, Gtk, that doesn't support Ada's tasking model.

According to [Dmitry Kazakov's "GTKAda Contributions" library](http://www.dmitry-kazakov.de/ada/gtkada_contributions.htm) :

> GTK+ is known to be task unsafe. In particular, all calls need to be made from the same task (thread).

I have no better suggestion than to read his documentation at that link, specifically the first section "1. Tasking with GTK+" which contains an example in Section 1.1, and - if you find it helpful - download and use his support library.

(If people think this should be a comment, I'll make it so)

Comment: [*§9.1 Protected Types*](http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/95rat/rat95html/rat95-p1-2.html#9) are are a good choice; also consider `Gtk.Main.Timeout` for periodic rendering.